# Javascript equivalent of R's dataVector[indicesVector]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, r

I have a Javascript array that I want to order according to the indices in another array. In R I can rearrange a vector using a vector of indices, but trying to find a Javascript equivalent has just brought up results for sorting, which doesn't seem to be what I want (I'm not making comparisons of the objects--I already have the order I want).

myArray=[obj1, obj2, obj3];

myIndices = [1,0,2];

Desired output:

[obj2, obj1, obj3]

Comment: Some example of input and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: You could use the sorting method to reorder your array according to a secondary array.

Comment: @Morphyish -- example would be great

Comment: @athxp edit added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually didn't really understand your question until I saw your edit. As a mea-culpa, here is a vector based sorting method:

```
function vectorSort(arr, vector) {
    const matrix = new WeakMap()

    vector.forEach((indice, index) => matrix.set(arr[index], indice))

    arr.sort((a, b) => matrix.get(a) - matrix.get(b))

    return arr
}
```

with a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/v87ckz6e/1/) to a working fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `reduce` function.

```
orderVector = (vector, indices) => vector.reduce((a,v,i) => (a[indices[i]] = v, a), []);
```

```js
let c = [1,"first",3,4,5],
c_ind = [1,0,3,2,4],

orderVector = (vector, indices) => vector.reduce((a,v,i) => (a[indices[i]] = v, a), []);

result = orderVector(c, c_ind);

console.log(result);
```